# Is it considered safe to create a wallet on blockchain.info?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I created a wallet on [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info).

Why is blockchain.info is not listed on ["Choose your Bitcoin wallet"](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet)? Is the blockchain.info wallet considered safe?

Comment: I was considering to close this as off-topic due to "asking for service review", however it may be a public service to have an answer here... Vote as you may.

Comment: I confirm. It was not to have a service review. It was just to know why it was not listed in the bitcoin.org website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web wallets in general don't really make sense by bitcoin principles.

But to not make this into a service review: the wiki is managed in a git repository at guthub. Discussions happen there before changes are made. One such discussion happened here: https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/pull/663

Note that there may have been newer pull requests in the meantime.

Edit: per request, the gist of above link, the complaints about bc.i are:

> Bugs and losses: BC.i has suffered from concerning issues during the
>   past year (e.g. iOS denomination bug, weak key stretching, sizeable
>   number of users losing funds, and more issues I haven't verified yet)
>
> Backup/Password Security: BC.i hasn't adopted security features which
>   are slowly becoming standard in other wallets (e.g. BIP32, random
>   passphrases, backup on setup, rotating addresses, 2FA by default).
>
> Transparency: Source code of the app has been reset or not updated
>   repeatedly, making bitcoin.org often relay the false claim that the
>   app is open-source.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the gist of the discussion.

Comment: You're right. I tried, but was on mobile and it seemed like a lot of reasons. May give it another try soon.